# How to run a AWS lambda via SAM local that writes to an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I'm looking at running some of our AWS lambdas locally via SAM, including a one that writes to an S3 bucket. Is there a way of getting S3 to run locally, or talk to an S3 bucket in the cloud and write to that while running the lamda locally?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Where did you stuck?

Comment: I did several internet searches, but was unable to work out how to do it. I've got a lambda running talking to a local dynamodb instance but not s3.

Comment: @guijob Could you include the relevant code?

Comment: @jamesdwalker which error did you get when trying to send a file into your s3? local s3 is not supported yet but you can connect into your s3 cloud service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the way I achieved this (after much difficulty, the documentation is scattered all over the place and focused on specific use cases that weren't mine) was with [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack).

You need docker running, then:

```
pip install localstack
```

Then:

```
localstack start
```

[Some documentation I've found](https://github.com/localstack/localstack#overview) suggested that you use `http://localhost:4566` and indeed pointing a browser there shows something exists, but I got no luck pointing `boto3` or another AWS client there, getting very cryptic error messages.

The real port is 4572, try [this](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/604) out:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3api create-bucket --bucket mybucket --region us-west-1
```

And now if you have a lambda function like this:

```
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3' ,
        endpoint_url='http://localhost:4572',
        use_ssl=False)
    s3.create_bucket(Bucket="test-bucket")
    #rest of your function here
```

The final component (might depend on your Docker setup), is you may need to invoke it like this:

```
sam local invoke  --docker-network host
```